# iptables misconfiguration is blocking outgoing connections

Tags: debian, firewall, iptables

Here are the rules I setup..

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

When I try to make an outgoing connection, it gets blocked.

What's missing?

---

Here's the output from `iptables -n -L`

```
    Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           source IP range 93.0.0.0-93.255.255.255 
           tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source 
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 15 name: DEFAULT side: source 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:80 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:443 

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Note.. the first rule is there to block a particular range and the next two are supposed to limit the number of requests anyone can make within 60 seconds.

Comment: Could you run "service iptables status" or "iptables -n -L" and update your post with that info.

Comment: I updated the question with the output from the command.

Comment: Please elaborate on `When I try to make an outgoing connection, it gets blocked.`. What do you mean by an "outgoing connection"? What happens when the connection is "blocked"? Command outputs, logs, etc. would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any rules that would allow an outgoing connection. Why do you think it should work? Perhaps you're missing the fact that if you make an outgoing connection *to* port 80, the return packets are *from* port 80, not *to* port 80.

If you want to make connection *to* port 80, you have two ways to let the return packets in:

1) Allow in packets *from* port 80.

2) Allow in packets that are part of an existing session.

I don't see any evidence you did either of these things.

Comment: The OUTPUT policy is to ACCEPT, and the ruleset for the OUTPUT chain is empty. So outgoing connections should be allowed, no?

Comment: No. There's no rule to allow the packets in. Sure, you can send out the packets needed to establish the connection, but if your incoming rules block the returning packets, the connection won't actually work.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I saw your initial two-sentence answer and didn't think any more deeply about it. +1.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a bit on David's answer, you can allow in packets that are part of an existing session by adding the following rule to your `filter` table:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

Permitting input packets in the `ESTABLISHED` state will allow most all outgoing connections to work as you expect, including non-TCP "connectionless" stuff, such as DNS queries (UDP) and pings (ICMP).

Permitting input packets in the `RELATED` state enables you to receive ICMP error messages that may come back from connection attempts to administratively prohibited ports/hosts/networks and such.